# mySQL conditional select?

Tags: mysql, sql

table: `id`, `status`, `time`

```
$now = time(); // current timestamp

$statuses = array (
    'ST1' => 60,  // (seconds)
    'ST2' => 120,  // (seconds)
    'ST3' => 180,  // (seconds)
);

$query = 'SELECT id FROM table WHERE status IN("ST1", "ST2", "ST3") AND time ... LIMIT 1';
```

Now I want to select `id` of `1 row` from the table where:

If `status` is ST1: (time + 60) > $now

If `status` is ST2: (time + 120) > $now

If `status` is ST3: (time + 180) > $now

So that if the row has the column `status` = "ST1" it checks if the column `time` + 60 is greater than `$now` which is the current timestamp, and so on.

Comment: Check out `CASE`, you can use it also in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: `CASE` is almost never a good idea in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please edit your question and give it a better title, "mySQL conditional select?" communicates almost zero information.

Answer (score 3):

Just use basic logic:

```
SELECT l.id
FROM leads l 
WHERE ((l.status = 'ST1' and l.time > date_sub(now(), interval 60 second)) or
       (l.status = 'ST2' and l.time > date_sub(now(), interval 120 second)) or
       (l.status = 'ST3' and l.time > date_sub(now(), interval 180 second)) 
      )
LIMIT 1;
```

I'm assuming that `(time + xx) > $now` refers to seconds.  Also, I encourage you to use the database time, rather than passing it in.  (You can, of course, replace `now()` with `$now` -- or better yet a parameter -- if you have good reasons for passing the time in from the application.)

To be honest, I might put this in a derived table:

```
SELECT l.id
FROM leads l JOIN
     (SELECT 'ST1' as status, 60 as diff UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ST2' as status, 120 as diff UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ST3' as status, 180 as diff
     ) s
     ON l.status = s.status
WHERE l.time > date_sub(now(), interval s.diff second)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Note: The second query will probably be able to use the index `(status, time)`. And that might be a huge performance improvement.

Comment: I tried the 2nd query but it throws an error: ErreurColumn 'status' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: The example I gave in my question is a simplified version just to explain the case. But my real query should be as follows but it throws the error (ErreurColumn 'status' in field list is ambiguous), here is my real query with real statuses:

SELECT id FROM leads t JOIN (SELECT "OKQ" as status, 86400 as diff UNION ALL SELECT "PI" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL SELECT "CBK" as status, 60 as diff UNION ALL SELECT "NRP" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL SELECT "NEW" as status, 1 as diff) s ON t.status = s.status WHERE t.time > date_sub(now(), interval s.diff second) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE 
CASE 
    WHEN status="ST1" THEN (time + INTERVAL 60 SECOND) > NOW() 
    WHEN status="ST2" THEN (time + INTERVAL 120 SECOND) > NOW() 
    WHEN status="ST3" THEN (time + INTERVAL 180 SECOND) > NOW() 
END CASE
```

Comment: You can remove the `WHERE status IN ("ST1", "ST2", "ST3")` as the other conditions already implicitly meat the condition.

Comment: @RaulSebastian, wouldn't any id from the table with status `"ST4"` not also pop up in that case?

Comment: the CASE condition as you stated here, will never evaluate true if the status would be 'ST4'

Comment: was just a design suggestion, at least I would have done it like that. So in case the status changes not to refactor the query in two places

Comment: The IN-condition is redundant, but can improve the performance.