# mySQL conditional select (Part 2)

Tags: mysql, sql

My original question is here: [mySQL conditional select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909832/mysql-conditional-select)

Now after adapting the second code proposed by Gordon Linoff to my real statuses the query sould look like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM leads t JOIN
        (SELECT "OKQ" as status, 86400 as diff UNION ALL
         SELECT "PI" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
         SELECT "CBK" as status, 60 as diff UNION ALL
         SELECT "NRP" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
         SELECT "NEW" as status, 1 as diff
        ) s
ON t.status = s.status
WHERE t.time > date_sub(now(), interval s.diff second)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Now this query throws an error:

```
ErreurColumn 'status' in field list is ambiguous
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the query that produced error ? because `status` column is used with `alias` name there is no possibility to get that error in this query

Comment: Yes, and the column itself is named status

Comment: Also string literals should be enclosed with `single` quotes not double quotes though am not sure how `Mysql` will use double quotes. In some `Dbms` double quotes are used for `identifiers`

Comment: Please edit your question and give it a better title, "mySQL conditional select (Part 2)" communicates almost zero information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query, as written, cannot be producing that error.  If all column names are qualified, then you won't get the error (and the only unqualified name is `id`).

Presumably, your `SELECT` has more columns in it than just `id`.  You should either `SELECT t.*` or another method is to use the `USING` clause:

```
SELECT  . . .
FROM leads t JOIN
     (SELECT 'OKQ' as status, 86400 as diff UNION ALL
      SELECT 'PI' as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
      SELECT 'CBK' as status, 60 as diff UNION ALL
      SELECT 'NRP' as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
      SELECT 'NEW' as status, 1 as diff
     ) s
     USING (status)
WHERE t.time > date_sub(now(), interval s.diff second)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```